# Tooltip Visibility

Tags: silverlight, tooltip

I have the following code:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <!--<sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Description}" Header="Description" Width="205" />-->
    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Description}"    Width="232">
        <ToolTipService.ToolTip  >   
            <ToolTip Visibility="{Binding    }">
                <sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLinesVisibility="None" HeadersVisibility="None" Height="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding Contains}" >
                    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Code}" Header="Code" CanUserSort="False" />
                        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Description}" Header="Description" CanUserSort="False"/> 
                    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                </sdk:DataGrid>            
            </ToolTip>
        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

I would like my tooltip to show, only if there are at least one row in the `ItemsSource="{Binding Contains}"`

What do I have to write in the `Visibility` property? 
Something like

```
<ToolTip Visibility="{Binding Contains.Length > 0}">
```

But I can't figure out what the syntax should be! Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for an implementation of `IValueConverter`.  Having posted many such examples in the past I realised that a couple of more general implementations would work of most of the time, so I blogged them.

The `IValueConverter` you need is my `StringToObjectConverter` blogged [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200812150557/http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/06/09/yet-another-blog-about-ivalueconverter.aspx).  With the code for this converter in your project you can create an instance of it in a resource like this:-

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:StringToObjectConverter x:Key="CountToVisibility">
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <Visibility x:Key="__Default__">Visible</Visibility>
                <Visibility x:Key="0">Collapsed</Visibility>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </local:StringToObjectConverter>
    </Grid.Resources>
```

and then used when binding to visibility, in you case:-

```
 <ToolTip Visibility="{Binding Contains.Length, Converter={StaticResource CountToVisibility}}">
```

BTW, are you sure you want `Length` not `Count`?

Comment: Resharper says these 2 lines are never used:
             <Visibility x:Key="__Default__">Visible</Visibility>
                <Visibility x:Key="0">Collapsed</Visibility>

Comment: @bmanu:  I hear some say Resharper is an essential tool for .NET developers, funny that.

Comment: but it doesn't work so far - Does the resharper comment help?

Comment: @bmanu: Works fine, in my testing.  Try testing your binding, remove the `Visiblity` and all the clever content from the ToolTip and just use this `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Contains.Length}" />`. Does the tooltip display the length value you are expecting?

Comment: Yes it works very nicely - Sorry for the confusion, Resharper threw me off a little - Thanks Anthony!

Answer (score 3):

You are going to have to use a custom converter on that binding.  Visibility property is not boolean, it is an enum.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative way, you can use triggers:
Set visibility of your tooltip to Visible by default and add this markup:

```
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Contains.Length}" Value="0">
        <Setter TargetName="myTooltip" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
    </DataTrigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: I get 
The attachable property 'Triggers' was not found in type 'DataTemplate'
what is missing?

Comment: Oh, sorry. datatrigger is for wpf :(